# gridview summary showing template string insted of actual value

Tags: gridview, yii2

Below is My gridview code:

```
Pjax::begin();    
    echo GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'tableOptions' => [
            'class' => 'table table-striped table-bordered table-advance table-hover'
        ],
        'layout' => "{items}\n{pager}\n{summary}",
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'
            ],
            [
                'class' => 'common\grid\ActionColumn',
                'template' => '{add_custom} {list_custom}',
                'header' => 'Outlets',
                'headerOptions' => [
                    'style' => 'width:175px; text-align:center'
                ],
                'contentOptions' => [
                    'style' => 'width:175px; text-align:center'
                ],
                'buttons' => [
                    'add_custom' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
                        return Html::a(Html::tag('i', null, [ 'class' => 'fa fa-plus' ]) . ' Add', 
                            [ '/users/outlets/create/' . $model->id ], 
                            [ 'class' => 'btn btn-xs green-sharp', 'style' => 'padding:3px 8px 3px 4px' ]);
                    },
                    'list_custom' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
                        return Html::a(Html::tag('i', null, [ 'class' => 'fa fa-list-ul']) . ' List ( ' . $model::getOuletsCount( $model->id ) . ' )', 
                            ['/users/outlets/list/' . $model->id], 
                            ['class' => 'btn btn-xs blue-dark','style' => 'padding:3px 8px 3px 4px']
                        );
                    }
                ]
            ],
    ]);

    Pjax::end();
```

But in it summary is not working properly,
is showing me

> Showing {begin, number}-{end, number} of {totalCount, number}
>   {totalCount, plural, one{item} other{items}}.

Insted of actual values.

Comment: Are you using some custom GridView class or default one?

Comment: @Bizley Default one

Comment: are you are extending the `ActionColumn`? what with  `common\grid\ActionColumn` it should be `yii\grid\ActionColumn`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam its my custom class , Dose it affects any way. It works fine locally but not on server

Comment: Cant be sure untill i see the code, you should add any custom code that you have written and extended related to the problem please add the code for the class `common\grid\ActionColumn`